# How to check if the (default) value has not been set in the registry

Tags: c++, registry

I need to check if the (default) value has not been set in the registry using C++. Whenever the value has not been set and I try to access the value, the program crashes, and I don't know how to check if the value has been set. Here is the code:

```
DWORD valueLength = 256;
char* value = new char[valueLength];
auto queryValueErrorCode = RegQueryValueEx(key, NULL, NULL, NULL, (LPBYTE) value,
        &valueLength);
while(queryValueErrorCode == ERROR_MORE_DATA) {
    valueLength += 256;
    char* newValue = new char[valueLength];
    delete[] value;
    value = newValue;
    queryValueErrorCode = RegQueryValueEx(key, NULL, NULL, NULL, (LPBYTE) newValue,
            &valueLength);
}
```

This code doesn't crash by itself - when I try to access the value is when it crashes, so I have to check if the value has been set or not.

Comment: Which line does it crash on? The debugger should tell you that.

Comment: `value` is not initialized the first time.

Comment: And I would use `std::vector` instead of `new[]` anyway.

Comment: @TheRandomLabs: By calling `delete[]` on an uninitialized pointer, you probably corrupt the heap. That will cause crashes later on. C++ isn't very forgiving - that a statement compiles and doesn't crash immediately doesn't mean that the statement is correct. As for `RegQueryValueEx`, it just needs a pointer to a buffer. Windows doesn't care whether you use the stack, `new[]`, `malloc` or `std::vector` to allocate that buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (default) value does not exist until it has been set, so check the error code for

```
ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

before trying to access the value.